# ¿Como modificar el reloj de 17:10 a 5:10?

Tags: javascript

Necesito modificar este reloj que no salgan las 17:10 si no las 5 y 10, alguna manera:

```js
 function startTime(){
                today=new Date();
                h=today.getHours();
                m=today.getMinutes();
                m=checkTime(m);
                document.getElementById('reloj').innerHTML=h+":"+m;
                t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);}
                function checkTime(i)
                {if (i<10) {i="0" + i;}return i;}
                window.onload=function(){startTime();}
```

```html
 <div id="reloj" style="font-size:20px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un script, espero te sirva.

```js
function actualizaReloj(){ 

/* Capturamos la Hora, los minutos y los segundos */
marcacion = new Date() 

/* Capturamos la Hora */
Hora = marcacion.getHours() 
meridium=(Hora>12)?"pm":"am";
Hora =Hora%12
if(Hora==0){Hora=12}


/* Capturamos los Minutos */
Minutos = marcacion.getMinutes() 

/* Capturamos los Segundos */
Segundos = marcacion.getSeconds() 

/* Si la Hora, los Minutos o los Segundos
Son Menores o igual a 9, le añadimos un 0 */

if (Hora<=9)
Hora = "0" + Hora

if (Minutos<=9)
Minutos = "0" + Minutos

if (Segundos<=9)
Segundos = "0" + Segundos

/* Creamos 4 variables para darle formato a nuestro Script */
var Script, Final, Total

/*En Inicio le indicamos un color de fuente y un tamaño */
Inicio = "<font size=3 color=red>"

/* En Reloj le indicamos la Hora, los Minutos y los Segundos */
Script = Hora + ":" + Minutos + ":" + Segundos +meridium

/* En final cerramos el tag de la fuente */
Final = "</font>"

/* En total Finalizamos el Reloj uniendo las variables */
Total = Inicio + Script + Final

/* Capturamos una celda para mostrar el Reloj */
document.getElementById('Fecha_Reloj').innerHTML = Total

/* Indicamos que nos refresque el Reloj cada 1 segundo */
setTimeout("actualizaReloj()",1000) 
}
</script>
```

```html
<body onload="actualizaReloj()">
Aquí mostramos la Fecha y la hora:
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td id="Fecha_Reloj"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una función sencilla y hacer lo siguiente:

```
function startTime(){
   var today = new Date();
   var h = hours12(today);
   //tu demás código aquí :)
}

function hours12(date) { 
   return (date.getHours() + 24) % 12 || 12; 
}
```

Sólo fue cuestión de usar las matemáticas.